# Class variable refuses to work via "self" but works with class name (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, class, class-variables

I have a simple class and a class variable inside this class:

```
class QuotesToScrape:

    authors_list = []

    def __init__:
```

There is a line of code in a method inside this class (method is called from **init**):

```
def gather_authors_list(self):
    self.authors_list = some_value
```

This line does not work, variable authors_list still empty. But if I change "self" to class name it works just fine:

```
def gather_authors_list(self):
    QuotesToScrape.authors_list = some_value
```

No decorators used. I feel here is some importand trick I need to understand to prevent me from serious problems in future.

Added later. Important part: I have another class variable, "quotes", and it works just fine. Here is nearly full fragment of my code. Class variable "quotes" ok, class variable "authors_list" not ok.

```
class QuotesToScrape:

    quotes = []         
    authors_list = []   

    def __init__(self):
        for page_number in range(1, 501):
            page_url = self.make_page_url(page_number)
            soup = self.get_soup(page_url)
            if self.out_of_quotes(soup):
                break
            quote_blocks = self.parse_quotes(soup)
            for quote_block in quote_blocks:self.quotes
                quote = self.extract_quote(quote_block)
                self.quotes.append(quote)
        self.gather_authors_list()

...

    def gather_authors_list(self):
        authors = list(set([quote.get('Author') for quote in self.quotes]))
        if 'Alexandre Dumas fils' in authors:
            duma_index = authors.index('Alexandre Dumas fils')
            authors[duma_index] = 'Alexandre (fils) Dumas'
        self.authors_list = sorted(authors, key = lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1])
```

Added later. Problem solved. Changed last line to match directions from comments. This solved my problem, now method does not creates new variable, but uses existing empty class variable:

```
self.authors_list.extend(sorted(authors, key = lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited after edition in question: when you say `self.authors_list = ...` the class variable is not getting updated, instead a new object variable gets created, and it's available only to that class instance. In the case of `quotes`, you are doing any assignment, and instead, you do an append which gets reflected in the class variable `quotes`.

When you did `QuotesToScrape.authors_list` instead, you changed the class variable, and this get's reflected in other object instances you create afterwards.

Try understand your case with this example:

```
class Yes:
    a = 1
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def yes(self):
        if Yes.a==1:
            print "Yes"
        else:
            print "No, but yes"

class No(Yes):

    def no(self):
        if Yes.a==1:
            print "No"
        else:
            print "Yes, but no"
        Yes.a-=1 #Note this line

Yes().yes()
No().no()
Yes().yes()
No().no()
```

The answer of this is:

```
Yes().yes()
No().no()
Yes().yes()
No().no()
```

I hope going through this example would aid in understanding your knowledge of class variables. Let me know if you have any doubt. :)

Comment: Technically I called method that changed `author_list` variable right from __init__.

Comment: Thank you. Now my problem is solved, everything works ok.

Comment: Glad, you found it helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code creates **two** variables:

one in the class' namespace

```
class QuotesToScrape:

    authors_list = []
```

and the other in the object's namespace.

```
def gather_authors_list(self):
    self.authors_list = some_value
```

Variables are defined by assignment in python. So where you assign them matters.

Please note that from the object instance, through `self`, you can still reach the class variable: if it's not found in the object's namespace, the name is looked up in the class' namespace (and superclasses')

Comment: I have added extended fragment of a code: another variable defined in the beginning of the class worked well.

Comment: Please read my answer again. Please study python more deeply, on a proper book. Of course the `quotes` variable works: it is not assigned via self as the other one! It is reached via self and its `append` method is called. I give up

Comment: Thank you anyway. I see problem and see solution, my code works perfectly now. I hope some day I will understand also why method makes such a difference between "self.x = " and "self.x.append".